# Debugging callbacks in a C++ executable with devenv

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, callback

I have an executable that is built with MSBuild and CMake, because I want to stay out of Visual Studio unless I am debugging. I have a callback in which I can't tell if it is working correctly or not, so I want to debug it. The problem is if you open an exe with devenv, it just appears to open the entry point of the application, it doesn't actually load the source code that would let me set a breakpoint on the callback, and since it is a callback, all my applications main function does is register the callback, so I have no way of breaking on an event with the callback I want to debug.

I know I could do hacky things like put the callback code in main.cpp and set the breakpoint there, or I could just debug the solution that CMake generates, but what I want to know is if there is a way to just simply debug the application to where I can open all source files associated with the executable without opening the solution, just the executable? The reason I want to do it this way is mainly for speed, a dummy solution runs significantly quicker on my machine than a full on solution, and it allows me to work in a text editor that is much faster than Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

The WinDbg tool is that path I could know if you don't use the VS IDE as the debugging tool, it can help you to debug/load source code or others.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556911(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll give that a look and let you know if it helps or not.

Comment: @Trevor Hart, I look forward to hearing from you :)